# encode text in C

Tags: text, ascii, bit-manipulation, encode

my program reads several string from standard input. I want to encode it like this: where is A print 00,where is B print 01. This is my code. I don't know where I'm wrong. Thank you!

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<conio.h>
    #include<string.h>
    int main(void)
   {
    char text[100];

    printf("enter  text:");
    fgets(text,100,stdin);
    int i,j;
    unsigned int aux;
    char a[100];
    char b[100];
    for(i=0;i<100;i++)
    for(j=0;j<100;j++)
    {
                      if(text[i]=='a'){
                      aux=aux|0;
                      aux=aux<<2;
                      a[j-1]=aux;
                      a[j]='\0';
                      }
                     if(text[i]=='b'){
                     aux=aux|1;
                     aux=aux<<2;
                     b[j-1]=aux;
                     b[j]='\0';
                     }
                     strcat(a,b)
                      }
                      printf("%s", a[j]);
                getch();      
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`printf ("%02d\n", toupper(text[i]) - 'A');`

or

```
for (i = 0; i < strlen (text); i++)
    sprintf (&a[i*3], "%02d ", toupper(text[i]) - 'A');
```

Note that this only works for text only strings